Row Values to Column in ORACLE without using REGEXP(It is taking longer time)
Have value in row level
('111_122,111_142,111_222,111_322,142_342,212_232,222_242,312_332,322_342')
Desired output is in column level
111_122
111_142
111_222
111_322...
Used REGEXP function but it is taking longer time to fetch the data. Any other option can we use?

THIS IS THE INPUT :
CREATE TABLE TAB_A (VALUE VARCHAR2(1000));
    INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('111_122,111_142,111_222,111_322,142_342,212_232,222_242,312_332,322_342');
    
    COMMIT;


THIS IS WHAT WE WANT TO SEE AS OUTPUT:
CREATE TABLE TAB_B (VALUE VARCHAR2(1000));
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('111_122');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('111_142');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('111_222');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('111_322');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('142_342');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('212_232');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('222_242');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('312_332');
INSERT INTO TAB_A(VALUE) VALUES('322_342');
COMMIT;

Used REGEXP function but it is taking longer time:
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR (VALUE,
'[^,]+',
1,
LEVEL)    L_VALUE
FROM tab_a
CONNECT BY INSTR (VALUE,
',',
1,
LEVEL - 1) > 0

That's looking like a XY question, even if regexp_substr is slower than other solutions, there is no reason to have  big efficiency problem on small data sets, so give the actual DDL of the tables and their cardinalities, and the complete CONNECT BY expression used.

You really should have scrubbed your data better before bringing it into Oracle.  Assuming your target table is really just a single column, then I suggest:

Export your current table as a CSV file
Then open any text editor which supports regular expressions.  Do the following replacement:

Find: ,
Replace: \n


This should leave you with a single column of data in the editor
Finally, reimport your text file using SQL*Loader or other similar approach.


Thanks for your answer, it is only input and output table why I should use CSV file and SQL loader? Can you please go through my previous comments?
